# Gdb traces declaration of variables when exit from a scope

Tags: gcc, gdb

When you debug code generated with gcc 4.8, you get that each destructor has its own "debug_line" entry. For example, if you compile (g++ -g "file") and you debug (gdb a.out) this program:

```
class C {
public:
  C() {}
  ~C() {}
  int m() { return 0; }
};

/*  7 */ int main() {
/*  8 */   C a;
/*  9 */   C b;
/* 10 */   C c;
/* 11 */   return a.m() + b.m() + c.m();
/* 12 */ }
```

you get this output:

```
(gdb) start
8   /*  8 */   C a;
(gdb) next
9   /*  9 */   C b;
(gdb) next
10  /* 10 */   C c;
(gdb) next
11  /* 11 */   return a.m() + b.m() + c.m();
(gdb) next
10  /* 10 */   C c;
(gdb) next
9   /*  9 */   C b;
(gdb) next
8   /*  8 */   C a;
(gdb) next
```

How can I disable the output of these kind of destruction information from the trace?

I want to disable this information because the step by step debug in Qtcreator seems to me confusing.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way of disabling this behaviour too. I'm studying some 3rd party code and it's very distracting a this stage to keep jumping to the destruction points.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this.

gdb now has a "skip" command that can suppress stepping into some things.  But it won't suppress nexting in a function.

This kind of thing is a case of GIGO.  gdb is pretty much at the mercy of the line tables the compiler emits.  Maybe it is even a GCC bug, but you would have to dig into all the gory details to find out for sure.